# Missing Create Command-line Launcher in PhpStorm 2019.1

Tags: phpstorm

The `Tools | Create Command-line Launcher` is missing in PhpStorm 2019.1 (cf documentation : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#enable-cmd)

Does anyone know how to do it now ? (I'm on MacOS Mojave)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Create Command-line Launcher...** action is no longer available when the IDE is installed by Toolbox or Snap (the script hard-codes the installation path which changes with every update).
Please see **Answer** in [IDEA-206235](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206235):

```
The change is intentional, as generated launchers contain hard-coded paths and stop working after upgrade.

The recommended solution is using scripts provided by Toolbox (Settings | Generate shell scripts in TB app), which support same options as launchers.

At the moment, TB-generated scripts incorrectly pass arguments to the IDE on macOS, but the team is going to fix this (please follow TBX-3314). 
As a workaround, one may remove leading open -a part from the script.
```